# application error Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, httprequest

I am getting an `application error Errno::ECONNREFUSED` error when I try and send an HTTP Request. I'm using `Sinatra`, and have it set up locally on my workstation. Here is the error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - Connection refused:
    org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:124:in `initialize'
    org/jruby/RubyIO.java:876:in `new'
    org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:154:in `open'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    org/jruby/ext/Timeout.java:79:in `timeout'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
    ./ServiceRequest.rb:39:in `sendGetRequest'
    ./fileParser.rb:148:in `parseUrls'
    org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1181:in `each'
    ./fileParser.rb:138:in `parseUrls'
    org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1181:in `each'
    ./fileParser.rb:73:in `parseUrls'
    ./testmdxservices.rb:108:in `sendServiceRequest'
    ./testmdxservices.rb:80:in `getFile'
    TestServices.rb:71:in `TestServices'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:117:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1264:in `compile!'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `route!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:851:in `route_eval'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:835:in `route!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:872:in `process_route'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1212:in `catch'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:870:in `process_route'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:834:in `route!'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1620:in `each'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:833:in `route!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:936:in `dispatch!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `call!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `invoke'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1212:in `catch'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:921:in `invoke'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:769:in `call!'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:755:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:136:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:129:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:99:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1471:in `synchronize'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1389:in `call'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /Users/Banderson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
```

Here is my `sendGetRequest`:

```
def sendGetRequest(url, mMethod, key, rHash, headers, publicToken)



        mKey = String.new(key)
        nMethod =String.new(mMethod)

        nKey = mKey.concat(nMethod)

        uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url))
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
            headers.each do |hKey, hVal|
                request[hKey] = hVal
            end

        request["Authorization"] = publicToken

        if uri.scheme == "https"
            http.use_ssl = true 
            http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
            response = http.request(request)


        else

            response = http.request(request)
            response.body
            #response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
        end


        if response.code == '200'

            code = response.code
            puts "#{mMethod}: - Test passed! Response code: #{response.code}" 
            rHash[nKey] = code

            #puts "#{rHash}"
        else
            code = response.code
            puts "#{mMethod}: - Test failed! Response code: #{response.code}"
            rHash[nKey] = code
            #puts "#{rHash}"



        end
        return rHash
    end
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get this error. If anyone could help, that would be great. Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: What are `uri.host` and `uri.port`?

Comment: I'm passing in a `URL` which is: `www.myurl.more.com/service/something?expand=something(.(this))&that=something`. I'm assuming that the`uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url))` function is parsing that out. I guess I could log it, and see what is really in there?

Comment: `uri.host` = myurl.more.com & `uri.port` = 80

Comment: Can you do `telnet myurl.more.com 80`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the address should have been: `https://www.myurl.more.com/service/something?expand=something(.(this))&that=something` rather that: `http://www.myurl.more.com/service/something?expand=something(.(this))&that=something`